# React: How to correctly update state array? setState(state.concat(array)) not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

### Problem:

I cannot update useState by its value, array in React Native

### Background:

I develop recording app, and I want to keep the last 5 seconds, and update every 2.5 seconds:

[old audio data] (5 seconds) and [new audio data] (2.5 seconds)

-> (crop the first 2.5 seconds of old audio data)

[old audio data] (last 2.5 seconds) + [new audio data] (2.5 seconds)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import Recording from 'react-native-recording';

const App = () => {
  const [signals, setSignals] = useState<number[]>(new Array(24000 * 5).fill(0));

  Recording.init({
    bufferSize: 24000 * 2.5,
    sampleRate: 24000,
    bitsPerChannel: 16,
    channelsPerFrame: 1,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('start effect');
    const listener = Recording.addRecordingEventListener((data: number[]) => {
      const newSignals = signals.slice(signals.length - data.length, signals.length).concat(data);
      setSignals(newSignals);  // this doesn't work, but setSignals(new Array(24000 * 5).fill(1)) work. Why?
    });
    console.log(signals);
    Recording.start();
    return () => {
      console.log('clean up');
      Recording.stop();
      listener.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return (...
  );
};
```

console.log shows

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, ..., -42, 64, 78]
[0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 12, 22, 132]
[0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 10, -222, 121]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the previous state when updating.

```
const newSignals = signals.slice(signals.length - data.length, signals.length).concat(data);
setSignals(newSignals);
```

To:

```
setSignals(prev => prev.slice(signals.length - data.length, signals.length).concat(data));
```

Comment: It's best to always treat state as immutable. I think you could achieve that with something like this: `setSignals(prev => [...prev.filter((_e, i) => i < signals.length - data.length), ...data]);`